# merge one to many without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Hi could someone please help, how to merge the below 2 tables, without using the remove duplicates function.

```
    import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,2,3], 'product' : ['Phone','Car','Bike']})   
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID2':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 'price' : [30,50,30,50,50,20,60,40], 'location' : ['aa','bb','cc','dd', 'ee','tt','hh','yy']})

    ID  product
0   1   Phone
1   2   Car
2   3   Bike

   ID2 price location
0   1   30  aa
1   1   50  bb
2   1   30  cc
3   2   50  dd
4   2   50  ee
5   3   20  tt
6   3   60  hh
7   3   40  yy
```

The result I would like to get :

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,'', '',2, '', 3, '',''], 'product' : ['Phone','', '','Car','','Bike', '',''],
'ID2':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 'price' : [30,50,30,50,50,20,60,40], 'location' : ['aa','bb','cc','dd', 'ee','tt','hh','yy']})

    ID  product ID2 price location
0   1   Phone   1   30    aa
1               1   50    bb
2               1   30    cc
3   2   Car     2   50    dd
4               2   50    ee
5   3   Bike    3   20    tt
6               3   60    hh
7               3   40    yy
```

Comment: Do you mean `df2.merge(df, left_on="ID2", right_on="ID").set_index(["ID", "product", "ID2"])` ?

Comment: @Andrej Kesely worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can to a classical `merge`, then hide the duplicated`columns using`mask`:

```
df3 = df.merge(df2, left_on='ID', right_on='ID2')
cols = df.columns
df3[cols] = df3[cols].mask(df3[cols].duplicated(), '')
```

output:

```
  ID product  ID2  price location
0  1   Phone    1     30       aa
1               1     50       bb
2               1     30       cc
3  2     Car    2     50       dd
4               2     50       ee
5  3    Bike    3     20       tt
6               3     60       hh
7               3     40       yy
```

Comment: wouldn't that .duplicated cause problems that I may lose some data in a case where I have a table with 50 to 100k rows and 20/30 different cols?

Comment: unfortunately didnt work, maybe I should rewrite the ask

Comment: @SkittlesBrah yes please do, also explain in details what didn't work

Comment: I simplified a bit the code to handle an arbitrary number of columns